# Facebook Share link not working for Authenticated Urls

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to find an answer for this, I have added a Share Button to each post page of a forum that we have, to normally access the forum posts, a user login is required, when I click the share button, the facebook dialog shows me that the shared link will be going to our sites login page, I know this seems like a stupid question but is it possible for facebook to access a url like ours which requires authentication, thanks for answers in advance

Comment: _“is it possible for facebook to access a url like ours which requires authentication”_ – only if you _make_ it possible. F.e. by recognizing the FB scraper by its user agent, and then letting it access the resource without authentication. (Although that will mean, everybody else who sends that user agent will have access too.)

Comment: You should recognise the FB spider by user-agent and then return a page with only the open graph tags relevant to the resource and nothing else on the page. That way, anyone who uses the FB user-agent does not fully bypass the security - they can only see the og meta tags.